# TypeScript: Union type of objects without defining the whole type on each side

Tags: typescript

I am converting frontend Java to TypeScript and i am dealing with method overloading.

I want to write the types like this

```
const person = (info: {name:string, age:number} | {man:boolean}): void => {
    if (typeof info.man === "boolean") {
        console.log("man is defined", info.man);
    } else {
        console.log(info.name, info.age);
    }
}

person({name:"Joe", age:25});
person({ man: false});
```

But i have it like this to make TypeScript happy

```
const person = (info: {name:string, age:number, man?:undefined} 
  | {name?:string, age?:number, man:boolean}): void => {
    if (typeof info.man === "boolean") {
        console.log("man is defined", info.man);
    } else {
        console.log(info.name, info.age);
    }
}

person({name:"Joe", age:25});
person({ man: false});
```

I am hoping that there is a prettier way to define the types to make it more readable

Comment: You could use `(info: {name:string, age:number} & {man?: boolean}): void`

Comment: No i want one or the other, the intersect type would not work in this case

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible currently. There's even [an issue for it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1260), but it doesn't look like there's been much movement on that. For now the only way is with a discriminated union, a user defined type guard, or explicit type casts. Sadly none of those feel very clean.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript actually supports method overloading by specifying multiple function signatures. The last signature is the actual implemenation and will be hidden by the compiler.

```
function person(info: { name: string, age: number }): void;
function person(info: { man: boolean }): void;
function person(info: any) {
    if (typeof info.man === "boolean") {
        console.log("man is defined", info.man);
    } else {
        console.log(info.name, info.age);
    }
}
```

If you prefer to assign an arrow function you can define the overloads in a separate type.

```
type Person = {
    (info: { man: boolean }): void,
    (info: { name: string, age: number}): void,
}
const person: Person = (info: any) => {
    if (typeof info.man === "boolean") {
        console.log("man is defined", info.man);
    } else {
        console.log(info.name, info.age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go with default function overloading here, not exactly like your desired example, but much more readable:

```
function person(info: { man: boolean }): void;
function person(info: { name: string, age: number }): void;
function person(info: any): void {
    if (typeof info.man === "boolean") {
        console.log("man is defined", info.man);
    } else {
        console.log(info.name, info.age);
    }
}
```

The way this works is, that the compiler hides the signature of the implementation and uses the overloaded signatures for type checking.